# kafka consumer group no active members intermittantly and CURRENT-OFFSET back in time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am facing an issue where when i run

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --bootstrap-server <bootstrapserverip> --describe --group <consumergroupname>
```

Intermittently the job would fail saying

```
Consumer group '<consumergroupname>' has no active members
```

but intermittently it would respond with correct response.

```
GROUP   TOPIC         PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
cg1 topic2            14         209524208       209879940       355732          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            12         209661131       210015132       354001          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            18         210596316       210950268       353952          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            16         209437072       209793799       356727          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            22         211312375       211673261       360886          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            20         209286701       209650677       363976          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            2          210321827       210682351       360524          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            0          210421336       210776016       354680          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            6          209935369       210286403       351034          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            4          208701050       209058578       357528          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            10         209797150       210156390       359240          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            8          208526200       208878857       352657          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            13         209273989       209620027       346038          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            11         209654494       210012412       357918          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            17         209829801       210185017       355216          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            15         209905341       210265460       360119          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            21         208954845       209300246       345401          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            19         210387555       210742817       355262          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            23         209783280       210142947       359667          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            1          209766493       210129508       363015          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            5          211081940       211448467       366527          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            3          209639183       209995993       356810          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            9          210779405       211135365       355960          -               -               -
cg1 topic2            7          210334295       210696755       362460          -               -               -
```

```
GROUP TOPIC         PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                     HOST            CLIENT-ID
cg1 topic1              2          210682265       210682423       158             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              3          209995897       209996070       173             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              0          210775935       210776068       133             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              22         211673178       211673331       153             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              4          209058500       209058656       156             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              12         210015060       210015188       128             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              23         210142871       210142999       128             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              9          211135271       211135445       174             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              17         210184937       210185080       143             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              6          210286316       210286487       171             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              14         209879858       209880001       143             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              20         209650572       209650751       179             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              10         210156308       210156454       146             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              18         210950184       210950319       135             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              15         210265372       210265540       168             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              7          210696670       210696831       161             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              21         209300166       209300313       147             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              1          210129409       210129597       188             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              19         210742743       210742883       140             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              11         210012327       210012473       146             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              16         209793705       209793877       172             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              8          208878764       208878921       157             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              13         209619942       209620088       146             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
cg1 topic1              5          211448376       211448533       157             consumer-1-c4832c4d-678d-43c8-9f53-ae74626e0b03 /10.32.86.191   consumer-1
```

While the consumer is running all the time. And retention period is 24 hours so it should not be an issue. Interestingly there are 2 topics same job is listening from and this behaviour is happening only on 1 topic. There are no exceptions/logs on the consumer side.

Even if kafka detects the consumer to be dead (no active members intermittantly), the consumer's current offset should not go back in time right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's understand how consumer group describe command works.

1. when we run the command with n number of broker ips, the call is sent to 1 broker (Let's say A).
2. The broker chooses another broker which it believes is least loaded (Let's say B) and fires a FIND_COORDINATOR request.
3. The coordinator for consumer group (let's say consumerGroupName) is the broker, which is partition leader of __consumer_offset topic's partitionid = "consumerGroupName".hashCode() % (number of partitions in __consumer_offset topic)

   For example lets say there are 50 partitions in __consumer_offset topic. The coordinator for consumer group "test-consumer-group" will be the broker who is leader for partitionid  "test-consumer-group".hashCode()%50
4. Now that broker A knows the coordinator broker, it will send request to the coordinator for the latest offset details. The consumer detail may not be present if

   a. the consumer was never live

   b. the ttl for __consumer_offset is less than the last active time for consumer group.

   c. the replication factor for __consumer_offset is 1 and there was data loss for the particular partition.

In our case we had increased the number of partition for __consumer_offset topic (which is [very wrong thing to do](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10182) as it will render all the consumer group hashes inconsistent.) but also did not restart all the brokers. Because of this at times some brokers were chosen as coordinator but they were not aware of the consumer group, hence no consumer group active error was coming.